# Running cargo build after OS upgrade (on an old Rust project) says I am missing several system dependencies. Is this normal?

Tags: ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.

I had already installed build-essentials on my machine but I still ran into several system dependencies in a row when I was running `cargo build` that I'd never seen before.  In fact I have never seen cargo complain about missing system dependencies before (I am new to Rust, so take that with a grain of salt).

The list of dependencies missing included cmake, x11, expat, openssl-dev, freetype2, -lsqlite3.

Is this normal and to be expected?  Or is something wrong with my setup after my recent OS install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies you need depend on the project.  The package `build-essential` on Debian and Ubuntu is the set of system packages you can automatically assume is available when building an OS package (that is, a standard Debian package).  It includes things like the C compiler, but doesn't include shared libraries you need for various projects other than libc.

If your project needs other packages or shared libraries, whether it's a Debian package or not, that's fine and normal.  Many non-trivial projects require external dependencies, and those generally won't be installed by `build-essential`, so needing to install them yourself is expected.

Comment: My confusion is that previously I hadn't seen this issues arise.  That means either I happened to have had all thoe dependencies installed already on my previous machine, or cargo automatically taking care of those before and now is malfunctioning.  

That is my main concern.  Can you speak to Rust and cargo specifically?

Comment: It's possible they got installed for other reasons on your machine before.  All of those are pretty common dependencies and could easily have been installed by some other package, but whether they're required for your project just depends on the project and requirements.  Rust and cargo don't intrinsically need them any more than other software does; usually they're a dependency of some crate your project depends on.